# Getting Missing required argument $routerList of Magento\Framework\App\RouterList in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I'm getting this error message: 
`Missing required argument $routerList of Magento\Framework\App\RouterList`.

I copied my project from my server to my local. First I believed that is the config.php file is missing, but it is there.

This is the method from where i got this error:

```
protected function _resolveArguments($requestedType, array $parameters, array $arguments = [])
    {
        $resolvedArguments = [];
        $arguments = count($arguments)
            ? array_replace($this->config->getArguments($requestedType), $arguments)
            : $this->config->getArguments($requestedType);
        foreach ($parameters as $parameter) {
            list($paramName, $paramType, $paramRequired, $paramDefault) = $parameter;
            $argument = null;
            if (!empty($arguments) && (isset($arguments[$paramName]) || array_key_exists($paramName, $arguments))) {
                $argument = $arguments[$paramName];
            } elseif ($paramRequired) {
                if ($paramType) {
                    $argument = ['instance' => $paramType];
                } else {
                    $this->creationStack = [];
                    throw new \BadMethodCallException(
                        'Missing required argument $' . $paramName . ' of ' . $requestedType . '.'
                    );
                }
            } else {
                $argument = $paramDefault;
            }

            $this->resolveArgument($argument, $paramType, $paramDefault, $paramName, $requestedType);

            $resolvedArguments[] = $argument;
        }
        return $resolvedArguments;
    }
```

Comment: Hope this will help https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5031

Comment: After putting config.php, you need to remove cache as well using rm -rf var/cache/* no need to do anything in env.php

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In my `env.php` file from `app/etc` I had to change this part:

```
'cache_types' =>
        array (
            'config' => 1,
            'layout' => 1,
            'block_html' => 1,
            'collections' => 1,
            'reflection' => 1,
            'db_ddl' => 1,
            'eav' => 1,
            'customer_notification' => 1,
            'full_page' => 1,
            'config_integration' => 1,
            'config_integration_api' => 1,
            'translate' => 1,
            'config_webservice' => 1,
            'compiled_config' => 1,
        ),
```

into this:

```
'cache_types' =>
        array (
            'config' => 0,
            'layout' => 0,
            'block_html' => 0,
            'view_files_fallback' => 0,
            'view_files_preprocessing' => 0,
            'collections' => 0,
            'db_ddl' => 0,
            'eav' => 0,
            'full_page' => 0,
            'translate' => 0,
            'config_integration' => 0,
            'config_webservice' => 0,
            'config_integration_api' => 0,
        ),
```

This one, fixed my issue.

Comment: What this does is disable your cache. I'm not sure what the real issue was here, but that's not a good solution.

Answer (score 4):

Just run `bin/magento module:enable --all` to regenerate config.php, and then `bin/magento setup:upgrade`.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the similar issue and in my case, the issue was due to missing `config.php` in `app/etc`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. In my case it was related to the cache. Instead of disabling the magento cache I run

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

from the magento root directory to clean out all cache types.